# Iterating foreach loop only works one time

Tags: php, postgresql

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$rows = $db->prepare($sql);
$rows->execute();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
   echo($row);
}

echo("<br/>");
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   echo($row);
}
```

If I run this, I will get the first line of arrayarrayarray(...) but the second one is empty. Is there a way to be able to run this twice?

EDIT: I had a typo in this post, the original question stands

Comment: `$row as $row` doesn't make sense,.

Comment: What do you mean by _second one is empty_?

Comment: $row contains an array, you should use `print_r` instead of `echo` to get a debug output.

Comment: There was a typo in the post. By empty is that I mean there nothing was being printed. I know that print_r debugs arrays better, I just wanted to see if there was anything being printed at all which isn't the case. I just ended up copying the content to an array first and then foreach as many times as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$rows` is a prepared statement object. That object implement `Traversable`, so you can use `foreach` to fetch the results rather than directly calling a fetch method. But after you've fetched the results once, you can't fetch them again. You'll need to either execute the query again or store the results in an array during the first iteration and use the stored results the second time, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$rows = $db->prepare($sql);
$rows->execute();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $stored[] = $row;        // save the rows in an array
   echo($row);
}

echo("<br/>");
foreach ($stored as $row) {  // iterate the saved array instead of the statement
   echo($row);
}
```

Also, I'm not sure how `echo($row)` is working here since I would assume `$row` would be an array, but that's beside the point.

Comment: That's what I did! Thanks. The echo($row) doesn't really do anything, it was just a random example to put here in the post

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($row as $row) {
   echo($row);
}
```

I feel like this is a typing issue and should be:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   echo($row);
}
```

Just like your loop above that one.

Comment: I had a typo in the post, but the problem is still there when I run it (with the correct variables)